# Problema com a versão do Kotlin Gradle

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

Bom dia, estou desenvolvendo uma app com flutter e o aplicativo utiliza uma dependência chamada barcode_scan que serve para scanear QR code, na hora de gerar a APK o gradle da um erro com a versão.
Esse é o erro:

```
* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.10 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':barcode_scan' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.51
```

Esse é o codigo do gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Conheço pouco do Flutter mas nele não é gerado um arquivo para gerenciar essas dependências, aonde vc poderia modificar a versão do Gradle ?

Comment: O gradle não é gerado no arquivo de dependências mas no build.gradle que é o padrão para android